mailtrap not recieving emails sent from my webapp
I am trying to send emails from my webapp they are successfully getting logged in my laravel logs but not showing on my mailtrap I have tried eeven using my personal email to see if i will find a way ot but even the mails are not going through to my gmail account... i have double checked the mailtrap credentials and they are all ok,
i have even tried a test route but its still not working
this is he test route
Route::get('/test-mail', function () {
    Mail::raw('This is a test email.', function ($message) {
        $message->to('allanmurimi96@gmail.com')
                ->subject('Test Email');
    });
    return 'Test email sent!';
});

the code that I have been working on is as follows
controller
  public function SendEmailUser(Request $request)
    {

        
      if(!empty($request->user_id))
      {
        $user=User::getSingle($request->user_id);
        $user->send_message=$request->message;
        $user->send_subject=$request->subject;

        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new SendEMailUserMail($user));
            
      }
      return redirect()->back()->with('success', "Mail Successfully Sent");
    }
}


the mail class
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendEmailUserMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: $this->user->send_subject,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     */
    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            markdown: 'email.send_mail',
            with: [
                'user' => $this->user,
            ],
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
     */
    public function attachments(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}

the blade files
 <section class="content">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                     <!-- left column -->
                     <div class="col-md-12">
                        @include('_message')
                        <!-- general form elements -->
                        <div class="card card-primary">
                           <form method="post" action="">
                              {{ csrf_field() }}
                              <div class="card-body">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Subject</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject"
                                       required placeholder="subject">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>User (Student/Parent/Teacher)</label>
                                    <select name="user_id" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                                       <option value="">Select</option>
                                    </select>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label style="display:block;">Message To </label>
                                    <label style="margin-right: 50px"><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="message_to[]"> Student</label>
                                    <label style="margin-right: 50px"><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="message_to[]"> Parent</label>
                                    <label> <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="message_to[]">Teacher</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Message</label>
                                    <textarea id="compose-textarea" name="message" class="form-control" style="height: 300px">
                                    </textarea>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <!-- /.card-body -->
                              <div class="card-footer">
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Email</button>
                              </div>
                           </form>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.card -->
                     </div>
                     <!--/.col (left) -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.row -->
               </div>
               <!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </section>

default mail.php,,here I have tried changing the default from log to smtp and also changed the host from localhost as provided by laravell by default

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    'mailers' => [
        
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN', parse_url(env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'), PHP_URL_HOST)),
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
            // 'message_stream_id' => env('POSTMARK_MESSAGE_STREAM_ID'),
            // 'client' => [
            //     'timeout' => 5,
            // ],
        ],

        'resend' => [
            'transport' => 'resend',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs -i'),
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],

        'failover' => [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp',
                'log',
            ],
        ],

        'roundrobin' => [
            'transport' => 'roundrobin',
            'mailers' => [
                'ses',
                'postmark',
            ],
        ],

    ],

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

];

the .env file I have double checked my mailtrap credentials also
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=84e6e4578fb2bc
MAIL_PASSWORD=083f996a91cec7
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@yourdomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"


Already tried using another port? Also what Laravel version are you using. If you are using Laravel 9 or higher try setting the MAIL_ENCRYPTION to null
